# Laravel 5.4 Session not storing

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I am trying to get a simple session to store a value but am having trouble saving it.
I have looked around at similar posts about this and tried their suggestions without any luck. Here is what I have done:

Use "web" in middlewareGroups

```
Route::group(['middlewareGroups' => ['web']], function() {
    ...
```

Use "web" in middleware and also manually

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {
    ...
```

and

```
$this->middleware('web');
```

Used`Session::put`, `session()` global and `$request->session()` and even `$_SESSION`

[Found this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769388/laravel-session-always-changes-every-refresh-request-in-laravel-5-4) and tried the answer but still nothing. I am using files to store my sessions

Added the following to my Kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class
    ],

    'api' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

And yet nothing! Perhaps you guys can shed some light? Many thanks.

Comment: Where are the files stored and what are the access rules to the folder? The web-server need write access to be able to store the session files there

Comment: Why are you starting the session twice?

Comment: I think your issue is having StartSession in both global and the web group. Try removing all but CheckForMaintenanceMode from $middleware.

Comment: Afraid not, when removing those it results in error: _Session store not set on request_

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem in Laravel 5.4

I found that adding the **save** method solved the problem.

```
Session::put('key', $value);
Session::save();
```

Hope it helps. Cheers.