# Laravel 5.4 on Google Cloud TokenMismatchException

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, laravel-5.4

Anyone deployed Laravel 5.4 on Google Cloud?

I need help as I keep getting **TokenMismatch Exception - VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68** irrespective of adding `{{ Session::token() }}` or `{{ csrf_token() }}`.

After debugging, I have observed that on page refresh one new page load the `token` keeps changing + **Session gets deleted**.
Thus, I have added the `Post deploy scripts`

```
"post-deploy-cmd": [
"chmod -R 777 storage",
"chmod -R 777 bootstrap\/cache",
"php artisan cache:clear",
"php artisan key:generate"
]
```

Here's the `session.php` file

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Session Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
| requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
| you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
|
| Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
|            "memcached", "redis", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 120,

'expire_on_close' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Encryption
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
| should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
| automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
|
*/

'encrypt' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session File Location
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
| files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
| location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
|
*/

'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Connection
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
| connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
| correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
|
*/

'connection' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
| should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
| provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
|
*/

'table' => 'sessions',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cache Store
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "apc" or "memcached" session drivers, you may specify a
| cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value must
| correspond with one of the application's configured cache stores.
|
*/

'store' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Sweeping Lottery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
| rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
| happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
|
*/

'lottery' => [2, 100],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
| instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
| new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
|
*/

'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
| be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
| your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
|
*/

'path' => '/',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTPS Only Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
| to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
| the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
|
*/

'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTP Access Only
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
| value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
| the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
|
*/

'http_only' => true,

];
```

Tried all available options but it's not helping.

TIA
[image]
[image]

## EDIT 1 [Added the AJAX call]

HTML

```
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

AJAX

```
     submitButton: '#seller_contact button[type="submit"]',
    submitHandler: function (validator, form, submitButton) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: '...',
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(xhr.message);
                alert(xhr.messages);
                console.log(xhr);
                alert(thrownError);
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#premium-contact-form").html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    },
```

Comment: Just out of interest - have you trialled the cookie session driver?

Comment: @AaronFahey Sorry I'm not aware of that, can you please describe more on that?

Comment: Try change your `.env` `SESSION_DRIVER` section and set it equal to `cookie` - I'm just interested to see if this gets 'around' the issue. This basically stores the session in an encrypted cookie, rather than on the filesystem.

Comment: Sure, I have made the changes and pushing the content to production stage i.e. Google Cloud, I shall update the same with the result

Comment: have you had any luck?

Comment: it's still uploading but after few more test cases, I observed that it's happening only for "Ajax" call but I have the "<meta tag" added too plus the input

Comment: Try adding it to your ajax

$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="token"]').attr('content') } });

Comment: @silverFoxA and you've added the required HTML that actually injects the token into the page?

Comment: @AaronFahey I think the `SESSION_DRIVER` did the trick.. Please put it as answer, I'll verify and accept the same

Comment: @silverFoxA just done it then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the cookie session driver, by changing the `SESSION_DRIVER` section in your .env file to `cookie`. This will store each user's session in an encrypted cookie, rather than on the filesystem.

Comment: The above along with https://stackoverflow.com/a/42769727 solution solved my issue. Don't why `file` `SESSION_DRIVER` didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try to send `_token` field in request;

```
let token = $('input[type=hidden]').val();
$.post('/...', {_token: token, ...})
    .done(function (result) {
        $("#premium-contact-form").html(result);
    })
    .error(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(xhr.message);
        alert(xhr.messages);
        console.log(xhr);
        alert(thrownError);
    });
```

Comment: The `token` value is being passed through `data: $(form).serialize()` form serialisation