# Session resets on every page reload

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.3

I was developing a laravel application on my windows machine and project was working fine there. The project was synced with dropbox and when i moved to mac my laravel project is not working here on macos.
The issue i am facing is that it regenerates session id on each page reload. I am using database as session storage and it adds a new entry in database. 
I have tried using file driver as session storage and same thing happens that it creates a new file in storage/framework/session which justifies that file permissions are ok and writeable.
All of my forms have stopped working and getting

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php
```

Permission of storage folder and session folder is 755

[image]

Each reload on the application adds a new entry in the db as i am using database driver to save session

[image]

Below is my session file

```
<?php
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => 120,

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "apc" or "memcached" session drivers, you may specify a
    | cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value must
    | correspond with one of the application's configured cache stores.
    |
    */

    'store' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => true,

];
```

As i mentioned same project is running fine on my windows machine and not working on my macos due to session issue. I tried many solutions online but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Please give more details about your configurations

Comment: I have added more detail.

Comment: What is your SESSION_DOMAIN in env file ?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769388/laravel-session-always-changes-every-refresh-request-in-laravel-5-4

Comment: APP_URL=http://localhost/trade_front
SESSION_DOMAIN=http://localhost/trade_front

App URL and Session domain are same

Comment: What is the cookie name?  Did you check in your browser and see if it is being set with a session id?

Comment: cookie name is laravel_session and it is not setting on localhost

Comment: can you see that cookie on your browser?

Comment: No this cookie in not setting i cannot see it under Application -> Cookies

Comment: have you include csrf field in your form?

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like a variation of a long time issue when using cookies with localhost as a domain.  In short, you can't do it, because in many browsers a domain name requires 2 '.' characters in the domain name at minimum.

These are ok:

```
www.domain.com
.domain.com
```

This issue has been discussed in various places, and in particular to php (which Laravel is beholden to) in the manual and comments for [set cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#73107) and in particular the section on 'domain':

> The (sub)domain that the cookie is available to. Setting this to a
> subdomain (such as 'www.example.com') will make the cookie available
> to that subdomain and all other sub-domains of it (i.e.
> w2.www.example.com). To make the cookie available to the whole domain
> (including all subdomains of it), simply set the value to the domain
> name ('example.com', in this case).
>
> Older browsers still implementing the deprecated » RFC 2109 may
> require a leading . to match all subdomains.

A simple way around this, is to put an alias in your /etc/hosts file for a domain of your choosing.  The best option, according to [rfc2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606) is to use .test at the TLD.

```
// /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost www.yourbogusdomain.test
```

Just as an aside, reasons like this are why I use Vagrant/virtualbox/docker.  You are probably going to be hosted on a linux server, so why develop on Windows/Mac OS, using a bunch of workarounds, along with WAMP/MAMP/whatever clogging up your machine with services that you will have to start/stop all the time, not to mention install/upgrade?

Last but not least, virtualization and the networking options it provides allow you to setup clusters and test out advanced multi-host configurations that would be messy at best to try and configure on your workstation as a series of interconnected processes.