# Laravel TokenMismatch Exception when sending token in header

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5.3, csrf-protection

I am sending *CSRF* token in header while making an ajax request.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': getCookie("XSRF-TOKEN")
    }
});
```

In the above code I am getting the token from "`XSRF-TOKEN`" cookie and setting in "`X-CSRF_TOKEN`" header globaly for all ajax requests.

I've checked in chrome developers tool that this header is being sent.

But **Laravel** still throws **TokenMismatch** exception.

**Note** I can not get token from html like meta tag or input fields becuase html content is being cached therefore I would like to set use "XSRF-TOKEN" cookie that laravel sets in every response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token generated by Laravel's `csrf_token()` and the one that is set in the cookie are not the same.

Now the problem is the "X-CSRF-TOKEN" header is used to send token generated by `csrf_token()` function.

Therefore if you want to send csrf token obtained from cookie you should use "X-XSRF-TOKEN" header.

Hence the above code should be like

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-XSRF-TOKEN': getCookie("XSRF-TOKEN")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like this instead:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Add this to your `<head></head>` inside your blade file

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And in your JS get the token like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').val()
    }
});
```

-- **edit** --

You can use an input field instead if you do not want to use a `meta` tag and put this in your `<body></body>`

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf-token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name="csrf-token"]').val()
```

Comment: I can't use meta tag to get csrf token for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem like yours; maybe this answer will help ..It look like your csrf token is updated : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43893114/5586645