# CSRF Token not work on server, The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE

Tags: laravel, cpanel

I have been working through this error for days and here are the issue

My project work on localhost properly, I just uploaded it to server and this error show up!
Here are some facts:

- CSRF Token are work correctly under FORM and there is nothing wrong with it as it was in localhost
- I tried many solutions either to change cookie name or  SESSION_DOMAIN to .mydomain.com
  as it shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769388/laravel-session-always-changes-every-refresh-request-in-laravel-5-4)

My Form is like

```
<form method="POST" action="{URL SUPPOSED TO BE PATCH}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
 <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
 <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{Key}">
  ...
</form>
```

MY .env file

```
APP_NAME=name
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY={key}
APP_DEBUG=ture
APP_URL={APP URL}

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE={DB NAME}
DB_USERNAME={USER NAME}
DB_PASSWORD={PASSWORD}

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379


SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN={.mydomain.com}


PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
ACTIVITY_LOGGER_ENABLED = true
```

My Session.php file

```
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    'encrypt' => false,

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),

    'table' => 'sessions',

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    'cookie' => 'test',

    'path' => '/',

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true),

    'http_only' => true,

    'same_site' => null,
```

**ALSO**, I have two projects with same error but not same version
first project which is data above is `6.20.30` Version
and second  is `7.28.4`

Comment: laravel version??

Comment: I have two project on server with same error, first which his data is above is Version 6.20.30 and second is 7.28.4

Comment: did you run php artisan optimize:clear? The error suggests that there is no route (this is not a csrf error)

Comment: I believe you didn't pass the csrf token properly. You should follow the documentation and use `@method('PATCH')` and `@csrf`. Otherwise use ` <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` Also, as another user pointed out, you may want to clear you app cache. When in doubt I run the following command to clear everything: `php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear && composer dump-autoload && php artisan view:clear && php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved !**

the whole problem was in The `Content-Length` header in request

if I exceed - that what happened - size limit of body content sending to request using METHOD **PATCH** it will send request as **POST**

You can change size of  your `content-length` through **php.ini** in your php folder in local or in MultiPHP INI Editor in my case (cpanel) by setting

```
post_max_size=500m
upload_max_filesize=500m
```

500m refer to 500 Mega (you can minimize or maximize it as you want)

then you should restart your apache server in local
`sudo service apache2 restart`
or restart it via WHM in server - You should have root Access -.